# Fetching data from a JSON object (from a given API) in AngulaJS

Tags: json, angularjs, api

I have the following code to present data from a link (API) as suggestion for an autocomplete box. Although it is working for one link and not the other. I observed that data format for both are different, modified my code accordingly but it is still not helpful.

.js file:

```js
var plunker= angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngGrid']);
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $window, $http, limitToFilter) {

$scope.cities = function (cityName) {
    return $http.jsonp("http://mtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/institute").then(function           (response) {
 return response[0].description;
    });
};
}
```

HTML file:

```html
<input type="text" id="depn" ng-model="formdata.department"        
       typeahead="suggestion.description for suggestion in cities($viewValue)"   
       placeholder="department" class="form-control">
```

If you replace the cities function with this one,

```js
 $scope.cities = function (cityName) {
    return $http.jsonp("http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=JSON_CALLBACK   &filter=US&q=" + cityName).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};``
```

Even after I changed my code jsonP request to .get, it is still not working

```
var plunker= angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngGrid']);
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $window, $http, limitToFilter) {
  $scope.cities = function (cityName) {
    return $http.get("http://mtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/institute").success(function(data) {
       return data[0].description;
    });
  };
}
```

It is working fine.
Is there a problem with my code, or a back end server issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out lately. Apart from the problem at back end there were issues in this code as well. I was returning the promise, but promise was never resolved to return the value also I was trying to return a string, whereas I should return array of strings. Here's the change:

```
 $scope.aap = result.data;
  var res = [];
  res.push($scope.aap[0].Description);
  return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your cities function to use the data property of the response in your .then (that's how you'll access the response from a resolved HttpPromise):

```
var plunker= angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngGrid']);
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $window, $http, limitToFilter) {

$scope.cities = function (cityName) {
    return $http.get("http://mtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/institute").then(function           (response) {
         return response.data[0].description;
    });
};
```

**EDIT**

Even making that code change won't solve your problem. This url does not support cross-origin requests, so you either need to host your angularjs app on the same domain and use a plain $http.get instead of $http.jsonp, or this url needs to support JSONP requests (the content-type of the response from this url is application/json. For JSONP to work it should be application/javascript).

Comment: It is still not working, here's plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cHP5eNf5fRTN7jBd2GGV?p=preview

Comment: If I make an error handler, will i be able to see the suggestion in autocomplete box.?

Comment: also i am getting this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/institute. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Since you're not making the request from the same domain, CORS is kicking in and making an OPTIONS request to that server to see if it supports cross-origin requests. Looks like it doesn't.

Comment: See my updated edit - if you don't have access to make the changes I'm suggesting, this won't work.

Comment: so is it a issue at back end, and that my code is correct ?

Comment: Your code is correct if you change it to what I've suggested. The webservice endpoint you're hitting will need to support this functionality as well.